# Arduino 5V Stepper Motor Moving Extremely Slowly

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, motordriver

I have a Stepper Motor 5V 4-Phase 5-Wire and a driver board for it.

Unfortunately, I do not have the schematics and cannot find them anywhere on the internet for the driver board. Anyways, I connected everything as it was supposed to be and punched in the code (see below), and it works fine but it spins at about 20 RPM, which is horribly slow.

I cannot decrease the time for `delayMicroseconds()` anymore because if I do, the motor stops spinning, and starts to just vibrate loudly. Please help, I am stuck:

> (Port 8  is connected to IN1 on the driver, Port 9 is in IN2, port 10 is
>   in IN3, and port 11 is in IN4)

```
int Pin0 = 8;
int Pin1 = 9;
int Pin2 = 10;
int Pin3 = 11;
int _step = 0;
boolean dir = true;// gre
void setup()
{
  pinMode(Pin0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin3, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  switch(_step){  
  case 0:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
  break;
  case 1:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
  break;
  case 2:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
  case 3:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
  case 4:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
  case 5:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
  case 6:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
  case 7:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
  break;
  default:
  digitalWrite(Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
  break;
}
if(dir){
  _step++;
 }else{
  _step--;
}
if(_step>7){
  _step=0;
}
if(_step<0){
  _step=7;
}
   delayMicroseconds(800);
}
```

Comment: I am also new to Arduino and stepper motors so anything helps.

Comment: Can you post an image of your motor?

Comment: http://s4.electrodragon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/5V-4-phase-5-wire-stepper-motor-gear-motor-28BYJ-48-5V.jpg

Comment: I just found this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/BYJ48-Stepper-Motor/. Don't know if this will help you. Anyway my tip is to try an example code (there are a lot of example finding with google your motor)